# Can't find why a InputMismatchException is occurring

Tags: java

I am stuck in one spot on a program have that I writing that takes information from text documents and assigns them to three doubles. However, I keep getting at "Exception in thread "main java.util.InputMismatchException" error (full log below) which normally means the wrong type of variable is being asked to be inputted, but I can't seem to see why that would be the case.

Here is the log:

```
Enter file name: Ellipsoid_data_1.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
    at EllipsoidListApp.main(EllipsoidListApp.java:39)
```

This only one of three files, but this is where the problem is. Anything you can do to help would be fantastic, and I can provied the other files if need be.

Here is the full program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;



/** 
*This class prints a list of Ellipsoids.
*Comp 1210 - project 5
*Steven Manings
*Version 2/14/2020
*/

public class EllipsoidListApp {

/**
 * Reads file with ellipsoid data, creates EllipsoidList, prints EllipsoidList,
 * prints summary of EllipsoidList.
 *
 * @param args - is not used.
 * @throws FileNotFoundException required by Scanner for File
 */ 

   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

      ArrayList<Ellipsoid> tList = new ArrayList<Ellipsoid>();

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter file name: ");
      String fileName = scan.nextLine();

      Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

      String ellipsoidListName = scanFile.nextLine();

      while (scanFile.hasNext()) {

         double a = scanFile.nextDouble();
         double b = scanFile.nextDouble();
         double c = scanFile.nextDouble();

         Ellipsoid t = new Ellipsoid(null, a , b, c);
         tList.add(t);           
      }


      scanFile.close();

      EllipsoidList myEList = new EllipsoidList(ellipsoidListName, tList);

      System.out.println(myEList);

      System.out.println(myEList.summaryInfo());


   }

}
```

I have gone and added the contents of the data file here:

```
Ellipsoid Test List
Ex 1
1
2
3
 Ex 2   
2.3
5.5
7.4
Ex 3
123.4  
234.5
345.6
```

Comment: You have the data file and a debugger -- time to do a little debugging

Comment: fair, but I just been staring at it for the last 4-5 hours. I was hoping a fresh set of eyes would see something I missed. It is most likely very simple.

Comment: *Seriously*. At the present time *only you* can debug this since only you have the data file. At least print out the data as you read it to see what you're getting

Comment: The next token in the input wasn't parseable as a double. Surely this is obvious? And surely it is also obvious that you are never consuming the line terminators?

Comment: The first double read is on line two, but the value is a string "Ex"

Answer (score 1):

NomadMaker is correct in the comment. After opening the file you read the list name `Ellipsoid Test List` by calling `scanFile.nextLine()`. Now the scanner is positioned at the line `Ex 1`. After that you enter the loop. The first thing you do in your loop is call `scanFile.nextDouble()`. Since your scanner is positioned at `Ex` and `Ex` does not match the syntax of a double, you get the `InputMismatchException` that you reported.

I think that a solution is to call `nextLine()` once more at the beginning of your loop to read `Ex 1` (and next time `Ex 2` and so forth).

This might — and I’m only guessing here — also give you something to pass in as first argument to the `Ellipsoid` constructor instead of `null`.